# JAXB namespaces, what are the rules for elements and attributes?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

in the pile of specs I can't find the most basisc question:

I can/must always,

- annotate the default namespace element with `@XmlElement(name="myElement")`?
- annotate foreign namespace element with `@XmlElement(name="foreignElement",namespace="http://foreign")`?
- annotate default namespace attributes with  `@XmlAttribute(name="myAttribute")`?
- not annotate namespace of child elements, if some parent up the "java object tree" was already asigned a namespace? A parent not being a super class but just some object that holds a reference to the child.

But now what is the deal about foreign attribute types? This seems to work `@XmlAttribute(name="foreignAttribute")`. Does this always work? So the rule is attributes don't need namespace even if the are in local elements? e.g. `<myElement f:foreignAttribute="FOREIGN"/>`

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks I read your article already in the mean time :-) But you say when using @XmlType(namespace="XYZ") on top of the class you don't have to annotate your elements in the class? I have a List of enums in my class, and it is only correctly filled, if I annoate the List with a namespace value. Why is that? The enums are defined somewhere else. Thanks alot.

Comment: Have you tried setting the namespaces at the package level using the `@XmlSchema` annotation?

Comment: I don't really want to add a extra package-info class, or is there some other way? Actually I would like the namespace for all subpackages as well? Lead me in the right direction, please.